# Deserialize to real underlying type with NewtonSoft.Json

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

If I serialise an object to Json with `new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All }` then the Json includes the type names. E.g.

```
{
    "$type": "MyDomain.Customers.SubscribedToNewsletter, MyDomain",
    "NewsletterName": "top",
}
```

Therefore when I use `var evt = JsonConvert.DeserialiseObject(json, settings);` with *the same settings* I would expect it to inspect the `$type` encoded in the Json string and return an object of that type.

Instead, I get a `JObject`. I have no idea what the actual type ought to be without inspecting the Json string myself by hand in advance.

What is the correct route around this problem?

Comment: Yeah I get that, in this case I didn't, hence the problem.

Comment: Sigh. I wish people who voted to close questions would say why.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
namespace TypeNameHandlingTest
{
    using System;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    public class Foo
    {
        public string Bar { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var foo = new Foo { 
                Bar = "bar" 
            };
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { 
                TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.All 
            };
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, settings);

            object deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, settings);
            Console.WriteLine(deserialized.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
TypeNameHandlingTest.Foo, TypeNameHandlingTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

Comment: I think I've made a mistake with my settings on deserialisation. I was hoping to find out for sure and delete my question before anyone noticed but I see I'm too late. Thanks for answering - if I find a scenario that doesn't work I'll update my question. :)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I *wasn't* as I stated in the question, using the same serialiser settings to deserialise after all. In doing so I believe I've resolved the issue.

And gained a few more grey hairs.